# Row iteration over a dataframe to calculate values and add them to new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

Steps till goal:
create a for loop to go through every row in the dataframe and:

1. take X and Y column values to use them in the function
2. the function will generate a Longitud and Latitud values
3. **adding those values in the same row in new columns called *"Lat" and "Lon"***

At the moment, step 1 and 2 are working, but I can't get the append of every value in every column

What I have tried is:

Definition to use in the loop

```
def xy_to_lonlat(x, y):
    proj_latlon = pyproj.Proj(proj='latlong',datum='WGS84')
    proj_xy = pyproj.Proj(proj="utm", zone=28, datum='WGS84')
    lonlat = pyproj.transform(proj_xy, proj_latlon, x, y)
    print( lonlat[1],lonlat[0])
```

Loop:

```
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    xy_to_lonlat(row['X'],row['Y'])
```

This is the output, that is perfect:

```
28.667978631874004 -17.96430510323817
28.67957708337043 -17.96589718293177
28.680075373251725 -17.96652237896143
28.696094952446764 -17.971279315586795
```

But I need to introduce these 2 values into df, exactly into **df['Lat']** and **df['Lon']**

What I have tried is to append() them in lists that later I will insert into df, but it doesn't work:

```
aLongitud=[]
aLatitud=[]

for _, row in df.iterrows():
    xy_to_lonlat(row['X'],row['Y'])
    aLongitud.append(lonlat[1])
    aLatitud.append(lonlat[0])
```

This is how df looks like:
[image: how df.head is printed]

The function works with the 52 rows, I just need to get them into 2 new columns in the df:

```
28.667978631874004 -17.96430510323817
28.67957708337043 -17.96589718293177
28.680075373251725 -17.96652237896143
28.696094952446764 -17.971279315586795
28.69709953128404 -17.97089438970623
28.704102246479206 -17.97502030269029
28.714190480593878 -17.98059681820521
28.84284299081375 -17.943724718418043
28.85522495646711 -17.907748758676934
28.85497605095961 -17.915999785074945
28.834039353212727 -17.853402778875363
28.84368320877517 -17.790724992980966
28.8311955800612 -17.773218425619255
28.757725903465193 -17.735394629644425
28.75694932761218 -17.734865031953948
28.651232614536056 -17.75864104734293
28.647850336922037 -17.75586691138396
28.64510111053916 -17.756973867003158
28.54740295444906 -17.779646961686794
28.481011316595747 -17.871383348460515
28.598084805574075 -17.92779850800547
28.84869842152646 -17.898800401690675
28.730123181880874 -17.72687292142767
28.65501749037169 -17.759807688028065
28.586115587686052 -17.755714748146353
28.855549587948108 -17.90757529900783
28.62104314133748 -17.750679106650242
28.805231369924527 -17.76049570914483
28.842322764567797 -17.794590436117428
28.654662237239517 -17.761368473029265
28.652716177555675 -17.954686156568993
28.84441637529699 -17.789637146820752
28.812367721581616 -17.763087214328706
28.80648375432461 -17.75977264125206
28.713070037952928 -17.74394044409638
28.850159557661478 -17.898032389327415
28.84268417328949 -17.884610248902643
28.506075965709968 -17.87932721318885
28.60916367244466 -17.92715257476472
28.508055636889907 -17.879126662123344
28.593688218530882 -17.755496249789623
28.614870490264675 -17.753636080872226
28.453393338804933 -17.83975500058191
28.81927942283548 -17.97071265399719
28.632049774803967 -17.948276230580895
28.810197401802437 -17.7626526992656
28.81013751332894 -17.762176710792335
28.651195000175182 -17.757862000230173
28.491243000164914 -17.874658000300624
28.523693000166094 -17.87819700030406
28.56082500016691 -17.89452700031706
28.53126600016634 -17.878297000304332
```

How the df looks after looping the function >> The "none" issue:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nquQf.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses your existing `xy_tolonlat()` function with the pandas DataFrame `apply` method:

```
def xy_to_lonlat(x, y):
    proj_latlon = pyproj.Proj(proj='latlong',datum='WGS84')
    proj_xy = pyproj.Proj(proj="utm", zone=28, datum='WGS84')
    lonlat = pyproj.transform(proj_xy, proj_latlon, x, y)
    return lonlat[1],lonlat[0]

# I just made up this data
xs = [21000,21020,23000]
ys = [3000000,3000050,3000100]
df = pd.DataFrame({'X':xs,'Y':ys})

df['lat_lon'] = df.apply(lambda r: xy_to_lonlat(r['X'],r['Y']),axis=1)
df['Lat'] = df['lat_lon'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
df['Lon'] = df['lat_lon'].apply(lambda x: x[1])
df = df.drop('lat_lon',axis=1)

df

#        X        Y        Lat        Lon
# 0  21000  3000000  27.039540 -19.826207
# 1  21020  3000050  27.039996 -19.826026
# 2  23000  3000100  27.041129 -19.806152
```

Comment: It gives me an error.
The output should be
`Lat    27.0   27.0 `    
`Lon   -19.8  -19.9`

But it gives to you:
`Lat    27.0   -19.8 `    
`Lon   27.0   -19.9`

If you try your code with more than 2 inputs, it's when the error appear.
I have 52 rows.
This is the error I get:
`ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Comment: Ah I see what's happening - sorry, it was late at night when i answered :( I've corrected the original answer!

Comment: Now I get one more error: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`
I think it is because the 'lat_lon' new column has been filled with 'None'

Comment: Is there an extreme value in your x or y columns that would cause the pyproj.transform to return a null value?

Comment: Actually, even when pyproj.transform() returns a null the code still works for me. Can you confirm that this solution works for the first 10 rows for example? Using df=df.iloc[:10]

Comment: No, it doesn't work even using the first 10 rows. 
I have attached in the main post the 52 rows with the transformation function completed, no extreme values I think.
My notebook shows the error in the Lat column creation
`----> 2 df['Lat'] = df['lat_lon'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
      3 df['Lon'] = df['lat_lon'].apply(lambda x: x[1])
      4 df = df.drop('lat_lon',axis=1)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: Is the problem that in my code the column names are lower case 'x' and 'y' whereas in yours it's upper case 'X' and 'Y'? :s

Comment: I've updated the code to be the correct column names - hope that works!

Comment: I don't think so. That's just the name of the df column assigned. Mine are in capital letters.
The thing is, why the function runs and loops perfectly but then it sets 'None' to all of the 'lat_lon' introduced column? Attached in the main post a screenshot of it just in case.

Comment: No, that's not the problem, I already saw in the beginning you didn't have capital X and Y and I changed in my code

Comment: Are you applying the slightly modified version of your function that I have in my solution? I had modified it to return the function output.

Comment: True! you changed the print to return! A thousand times sorry. It works, Thanks thanks!!!

Comment: Haha no worries! Sorry, I probably should have mentioned that I changed it to return the values sooner, so I'm sorry too!